# Why didn't Christ outrightly discourage/condemn the taking of oaths in Matthew 23:16-22?

Tags: matthew, law, christology

Earlier on Christ while teaching the sermon on the mount he had actually discouraged/condemned the taking of oaths

Matthew 5:34 ESV:

> But I say to you, Do not take an oath at all, either by heaven, for it is the throne of God,

Yet later on when Christ is rebuking the Pharisees he seemingly corrects the process of taking oaths rather than discouraging/condemning it

Matthew 23:16-22 ESV:

> You blind fools! For which is greater, the gold or the temple that has made the gold sacred?
> 18
> ESV:And you say, ‘If anyone swears by the altar, it is nothing, but if anyone swears by the gift that is on the altar, he is bound by his oath.’
> 19
> ESV:You blind men! For which is greater, the gift or the altar that makes the gift sacred?
> 20
> ESV:So whoever swears by the altar swears by it and by everything on it.
> 21
> ESV:And whoever swears by the temple swears by it and by him who dwells in it.
> 22
> ESV:And whoever swears by heaven swears by the throne of God and by him who sits upon it.

Why didn't Christ outrightly discourage/condemn the taking of oaths?

Comment: In Matthew 5 Jesus discourages _his own faithful disciples_ from swearing oaths. In Matthew 23 Jesus  emphasises _the hypocrisy_ of scribes and Pharisees in the _manner_ in which they make oaths. I don't see that it would relevant to the second occasion to discourage all oath-taking _among those who did not follow him_.

Comment: @NigelJ,but his teaching was directed at his disciples and the crowd as mentioned in Matthew 23:1

Comment: . . . . . . who are also discouraged from acts of hypocrisy. Yes, agreed.

Answer (score 2):

In Matthew 23:16-22, Jesus doesn't merely address the act of taking an oath, but rather, He condemns the hypocrisy of those who enforce strict adherence to laws they themselves disregard. While the passage may seem about oath-taking, Jesus directs his criticism towards the teachers of the law and Pharisees, denouncing their hypocritical behavior. He describes them as 'hypocrites' or 'blind guides', highlighting their failure to practice what they preach.

Matthew 23:13 NIV

> “Woe to you, teachers of the law and Pharisees, you **hypocrites**! You shut the door of the kingdom of heaven in people’s faces. You yourselves do not enter, nor will you let those enter who are trying to.

Matthew 23:16 NIV

> “Woe to you, **blind guides**! You say, ‘If anyone swears by the temple, it means nothing; but anyone who swears by the gold of the temple is bound by that oath.’

In Galatians 3:11, Paul states;

> Clearly no one who relies on the law is justified before God, because “the righteous will live by faith.”

Taking an oath can be likened to inscribing a law upon one's heart. However, since no one can perfectly adhere to the law, their oath holds no justification before God. As Paul emphasized in Galatians 3:14, righteousness is attained through faith, allowing believers to receive the promise of the Spirit.

In John 4:23, Jesus converses with the Samaritan woman, stating,*"Yet a time is coming and has now come when the true worshipers will worship the Father in the Spirit and in truth, for they are the kind of worshipers the Father seeks."*  **This suggests that genuine followers of God walk in truth, rendering oaths unnecessary.**